# BootsFaces does not render area from ajax

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am trying to render a data table using ajax ([BootsFaces](https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/ajax.jsf)) according to the values provided in the form. Unfortunately, desired part does not render. I can see the ajax request is going in the network tab, but it does not do anything (Area does not render and this `searchPartialBean.getSearchList()` method does not get called). Below is my code snippet. Is there any issue in the way I am doing it ?

```
<b:tab title="Search">
<h:form>
    <b:row>
        <b:column mediumScreen="7">
            <b:inputText placeholder="Telephone number" label="Telephone number"
                         value="#{searchPartialBean.telephoneNumber}"/>
            <b:inputText placeholder="First name" label="First Name"
                         value="#{searchPartialBean.firstName}"/>
            <b:inputText placeholder="Last name" label="Last Name"
                         value="#{searchPartialBean.lastName}"/>
            <b:commandButton look="primary" id="search-form-submit" value="Search"
                             update="serach-results-table"/>
        </b:column>
        <b:column mediumScreen="5">
            <b:alert severity="info" title="Info">
                This will contain the search help.
            </b:alert>
        </b:column>
    </b:row>
    <br />
    <b:panel id="serach-results-table">
        <b:dataTable rendered="#{searchPartialBean.valuesPresent}" value="#{searchPartialBean.getSearchList()}" var="patient">
            <b:dataTableColumn label="Date" value="#{patient.firstName}"/>
        </b:dataTable>
    </b:panel>
</h:form>
</b:tab>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've wrapped a form in a tab. Both widgets define a namespace, which, in turn, adds a prefix to the id of each widget within. Probably that's the problem.

My first approach would be to add a colon to indicate you're searching in the inner namespace:

```
update=":search-results-table"
```

If that doesn't work, you can use the recursive search expression of BootsFaces:

```
update="**:search-results-table"
```

However, my favorite approach is to use a CSS pseudo class like so:

```
update="@(.search-results-table)"

<b:panel styleClass="search-results-table">
```